# How can I cycle plaza NPCs and order a teammate's clothes?

Tags: splatoon

I've seen prior team/lobbymates show in the plaza after a match. I [was told](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805617-splatoon/71902353) there's some way to order their clothes, even if I don't have the money to purchase them. What determines which teammates I'll see in the plaza and is there any way to cycle through NPCs to see player clothes from a previous match? Does it only show teammates from the last match or the one before it? If I reset the game, will I see additional past teammates or will it reset to no one? And how do I order their clothes?

Comment: While I cannot comment on the algorithm of which NPCs show up, the "ordering clothing" part is easy.  There's a NPC called Spike on the north-east of the map.  Talk to him once and he'll give you the ability to order clothing from other people.

From there, talk to an NPC, and press X on the WiiPad to make a order request.  Spike will ask what item you want, and procure it the next day. (In earth time)  Items ordered this way are more expensive then if they show up in shop though.  Likewise, if you don't buy it from Spike on the day he has it, you'll need to make that order and wait again.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to talk to [Spyke](http://splatoon.wikia.com/wiki/Spyke). He will unlock the ability to order gear from the people you see in the plaza. From what I understand, you see about 2-3 games worth of players in your plaza, so 15-23 (you don't count) unique ones to look at gear from.

Eventually, you will see "Order Gear" in the bottom right while looking at these players. The gear costs about 3x what it would in a shop. Spyke will order a maximum of one new item per day, and they are only held for one day. See here:

[image]

Comment: 3x the price of the shop does not sound right, would be some expensive gear.

Comment: @CodedMonkey every piece of gear I've seen cost 30-40k, so yes, it is about 3x. It factors in that you're picking gear that already has been un-randomized and that you don't have to get the xp to level up the gear.

Comment: Oh dang, I'd better start grinding for more money then since I ordered something from him and I'm broke!

Comment: @Seiyria I finally tried it again for myself. I distinctly remember it being a lot cheaper my first (and only) time as the clothing I ordered was in the shop the same day. I was below level 10, so maybe the factor is level-based, does anybody know?

Comment: @CodedMonkey it's possible that you picked a piece of gear that was not 4-stat and fully revealed. Lower gear would reasonably cost way less, but like I said -- 4-stat gear in the shop is about 10k, and if you try to buy one of those from Spyke (assuming it is fully revealed), it will cost 30-40k.